# need help using curl and php

Tags: php, curl

I have sent post data and received the response but I need to enter the otp and received user id in the same page.
How can I do it? Please help me, thank you!

```
<?php

         if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){

            $number = $_POST['t1'];

}

 $andv = str_shuffle('7f7b631de96ebb6b');   
 $data1 = 'mnc=45&mcc=404&isForRegister=1&appVersionCode=4&appVersionName=1.1&androidVersion=23&androidId='.$andv.'&deviceId='.$andv.'&email=null&advertisingId=7f5816c1-52e7-453e-bc30-ecc6cc05c1aa';
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://getdatagenie.com/datagenie/api/v1/user/update/deviceToken/?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,0);
$one=curl_exec($ch);
//echo $one;

$data2 = 'msisdn='.$number.'&androidVersion=23&androidId='.$andv.'&deviceId='.$andv.'&deviceType=ANDROID&timeZoneInSeconds=19800&appVersionCode=4&appVersionName=1.1&deviceName=Redmi%203S&installedAppPackages=com.jio.jioplay.tv,com.truecaller,com.cyberlink.youperfect,com.databuddy.app,com.utorrent.client,org.wordpress.android,com.touchtype.swiftkey,com.phonepe.app,com.swiftkey.languageprovider,com.getdailylife,cn.wps.moffice_eng,in.inspirelabs.grabon,com.amazon.kindle&networkType=WIFIoperator=airtel&mnc=45&mcc=404&macAddress=02:00:00:00:00:00&local=en&email=null&advertisingId=7f5816c1-52e7-453e-bc30-ecc6cc05c1aa';
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://getdatagenie.com/datagenie/api/v1/user/getOtp/?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,0);
$oone=curl_exec($ch);
$datav = json_decode($one,1);
$data5 = $datav[userId];
echo $oone; 
//$otp = $otp1;





  $data3 ='?userId=9389&deviceId='.$andv.'&androidId='.$andv.'&otp=390591&email=null';
  $ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://getdatagenie.com/datagenie/api/v1/user/getVerified/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data3);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,0);
$one=curl_exec($ch);
echo $one;

?>
```

In the 1st curl app details are sent.

In the 2nd curl register details are sent.

In the third curl I want to verify the otp with the response of the 2nd curl,
what should I do?

To get and verify the otp in same page what should I do?

Comment: replace userId=9389&deviceId with userId=' . $data5 . '&deviceId

Comment: ya tnks but top enter otp in same page what should i do